# React, Redux webpack error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, create-react-app

I just created a simple project with create-react-app with npm. I run the project and everything was ok. Then I installed redux with `npm install redux --save` and react-redux with `npm install react-redux --save`. I refresh the page again and it was working. Then I import Provider from 'react-redux' and wrapped my `<App />` in Provider and I got the following error.

```
(webpack)/buildin/global.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kahn/Desktop/react-redux-course/practice-rdx/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js'
```

Then I removed the import Provider but I am still getting the following error.

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kahn/Desktop/react-redux-course/practice-rdx/node_modules/webpack/buildin  /global.js':
  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kahn/Desktop/rea  ct-redux-course/practice-rdx/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js'
  Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kahn/Desktop/react-redux-course/practice-rdx/node_modules/webpack/buildin  /module.js':
  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kahn/Desktop/rea  ct-redux-course/practice-rdx/node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js'

  - compiler.js:76 
    [practice-rdx]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any problem with my npm?

Comment: Just to confirm you are importing like this right? `import { Provider } from 'react-redux';`?

Comment: Try removing `node_modules` and reinstall all packages with `npm install` (no further arguments needed)

Comment: Yes I am importing it like this. Let me try to reinstall everything

Comment: It seems you have something wrong in your path ''/Users/ar  ifbangash/Desktop/react-redux-course/practice-rdx/node_modules/webpack/buildin  /global.js''
There's something like a tab character between `ar ` and `ifbangash/Desktop/react-redux-course/practice-rdx/node_modules/webpack/buildin  /global.js'`

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlWebpackPlugin has a bad cache. Set it to false (temporarily):

```
const html = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(ROOT, 'src', 'index.html'),
    cache: false
});
```